# Making elements correctly layered with z-index css?

Tags: css, z-index

On this page http://londonsitedesign.co.uk/code/basic.html I am trying to place an image above a full screen slideshow, but behind my header. The image is a white gradient. I have given the image the style z-index: 0 which places it in front of the background, however it covers the header. How can it sit between the header and the background?

I noticed that the menu in the header is onto of the image but the rest of the elements in the head section are behind the white gradient image. Why is there this difference in the layering of elements?

thanks for any advice.

Angela

Comment: Please reduce your problem to a minimal test case, or at least provide the IDs and classes of the elements involved.

Comment: James Donnelly's solution is a good one, but if you wish to understand more about what's going on I recommend this short read about z-indexes: http://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
.container_24 {position: relative; z-index: 10;}
```

It will also stop the fade over the footer, which I wouldn't think you'd want, either.

Comment: @angela this is just one element. As my answer states you should give **all** elements with a `z-index` a relative position, otherwise the `z-index` will simply do nothing. I could have used this `.container_24` in my answer as an example, but instead I used `#header`. It doesn't deviate from the fact that they all need changing.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add `position:relative` to your `#header` (and any other elements with a `z-index` but no `position` specified):

```
#header {
    height: 157px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    z-index: 5;
    position: relative;
}
```